# How to write case condition to check particular value exist among multiple values in sql?

Tags: sql, case

I have a column in table which is having single/multiple value. I have to convert it yes/no based on condition.

example:

```
rendition_type_sys
distribution
uploaded, distribution
uploaded
single
```

I need to change the value based on condition. If column having distribution then value should convert as 'Yes' otherwise 'No'

Final Output:

```
rendition_type_sys
Yes
Yes
No
No
```

I tried one case statement but that is working for single value not multiple value-

```
case when ren.rendition_type__sys='distribution' then 'Yes' else 'No' end as rendition_type__sys
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should fix your data model so you are not storing multiple values in a string.

In the meantime, `like` should do what you want.  For your example:

```
(case when ren.rendition_type__sys like '%distribution%'
      then 'Yes' else 'No'
 end) as rendition_type__sys
```

Note:  In case "distribution" is part of an element name and you don't want that, you can check for delimiters.  In Standard SQL, this would be:

```
(case when ', ' || ren.rendition_type__sys || ', ' like '%, distribution, %'
      then 'Yes' else 'No'
 end) as rendition_type__sys
```

The string concatenation operator may vary depending on the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This below code would work assuming distribution is not part of any other discrete value; here is the code in a sample form:

```
WITH rt AS ( 
          SELECT 'distribution' AS rendition_type_sys
    UNION SELECT 'uploaded, distribution'
    UNION SELECT 'uploaded'
    UNION SELECT 'single'
)
SELECT CASE WHEN rt.rendition_type_sys LIKE 'distribution' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Col
FROM rt
```

You might consider adding a table with for these "tags" so that they are discrete.